# A question about a net in a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be any topological space and let $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded continuous function. Let

$\lambda = \sup \{|f(x)|:x\in X\}$.

From this, can we say that there exists a net $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in D}$ in $X$ such that

$\lim_\alpha |f(x_\alpha)|=\lambda$?

In addition, if $X$ is compact, what more we can say about it? I have begun to learning $nets$, $subnets$ in a topological space, so the question may appear trivial.

**Edit** The space $X$ can be assumed Hausdorff

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is bounded, or are you allowing $\lambda$ to be $\infty$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have assumed $f$ to be bounded that is I am not allowing $\lambda$ to be $\infty$.

Comment: The set you are suping over is a set of real numbers, so if it is bounded, then it has a lub. If $X$ is compact then $f(X)$ is also, and therefore closed, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an $x_n\in X$ such that $\big||f(x_n)|-\lambda\big|<2^{-n}$, so clearly the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has the property that $\lim_n|f(x_n)|=\lambda$. Thus, we can get not just a net, but a sequence.

If $X$ is compact, we can say more: in that case the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ must have a cluster point: either it has a constant subsequence at some point $x$, or $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is infinite and has an accumulation point $x$. In the first case it clear that $|f(x)|=\lambda$, and in the second case continuity of $f$ ensures the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, I have not assumed $X$ to be sequentially compact @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @srm99: My apologies: in this context I unconsciously assumed $X$ to be metric. I’ll revise that suitably.

Comment: I have edited that $X$ can be assumed Hausdorff @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You have written $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite and has an accumulation point. Is it different than saying  $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ has a convergent subsequence? I am new in this area. Sorry, if I have asked anything trivial. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @srm99: Yes, it is different: if $x$ is an accumulation point of the set, and $X$ is not first countable, there need not be a sequence in $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ that converges to $x$, even though every open nbhd of $x$ intersects $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott for your time and reply.

Comment: @srm99: You’re very welcome.